# Show that player I can always win a Nim game in which the number of heaps with an odd number of coins is odd

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-proofs, combinatorial-game-theory

Show that player 1 can always win a Nim game in which the number of heaps  with an odd number of coins is odd. This question is provided in Richard A. Brauldi's book on Introductory Combinatorics. I attempted the problem as follows:

A winning strategy provided in the book was to arrange the given heaps into subheaps of powers of two. Then, it is obvious enough to see that if there are an even number of like subheaps (for all like subheaps), then the game is balanced (first player loses); and if there is an odd number of like subheaps (for at least one like subheap), then the game is unbalanced (first player wins). Then the strategy is to balance the game every time the opponent unbalances it. If both players are intelligent, the game is just a matter of whether the game is initially balanced or unbalanced.

In the problem given, it is the case that each heap has an odd number of coins. It can be shown that every heap, when organized into subheaps of powers of two, will contain the subheap $2^0$. This is because, when forming subheaps, we will first form the greatest power of two first, then from what remains we form the next greatest power of two, and so on. Hence we will take the greatest power of two from the initial odd quantity. An odd minus an even is always an odd number. From this remaining odd number we will subtract the next greatest power of two, and again resulting in an odd number. So for $2^0$ to not be the last part of the subheap, it must be true that some greater power of two must be. Yet, all other powers of two greater than $2^0$ are even. And, as we've seen earlier, since we started with an odd number, and continuously subtract (even) powers of two, we will always end with an odd number. This shows that all heaps must have the subheap $2^0$. Since there are an odd number of heap, there are also an odd number of $2^0$ subheaps; hence, the game starts out unbalanced, and the first player is always the one who will win.

Is this proof valid? Does this mathematically convince the reader? I ask because I am still yet an amateur in combinatorial reasoning; hence I require constant affirmation from those more professional. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not certain where the question is posed in the text, but (esp if the problem was posed near the start) I suspect that you're not supposed to be using the winning strategy provided in the book. Can you come up with another approach/idea (maybe similar, but much simpler) that will work for the case of "odd number of coins is odd"?

Comment: the problem was posed at the end of the chapter, I believe it was intended that I use the strategy; and really, it was only an introductory chapter, so I don't believe it was expected that any other combinatorial methods other than that provided be applied. Is the proof I attempted at incorrect or inconvincing?

Comment: Please state the exact rules in the problem.

Comment: *Show that player 1 can always win a Nim game in which the number of heaps with an odd number of coins is odd.* This is all that was stated. And I believe that the author recommends using the methods he already gave. Namely, the one where we break the heaps into subheaps (of powers of two). And balance/unbalance the game.

Answer (score 1):

> In the problem given, it is the case that each heap has an odd number of coins.

This is false. There could several heaps with an even number of coins.

---

Note: Re the condition of "number of heaps with an odd number of coins is odd",
In the comments, OP stated that their interpretation is "That literally means that we have no even number of heaps, and no even number of coins in any of the heaps". To them, $\{ 1, 2, 4,6 \}$ does not satisfy the condition.
I unsuccessfully tried explaining that it means "That literally means we have no information about heaps with an even number of coins". To me $\{ 1, 2, 4, 6 \}$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: I believe you've misinterpreted my text. It is required to *show* why player 1 will always win, not *how* he will win. As you've precisely expressed: the winning strategy is to toggle between a balanced/unbalanced game, always leaving your opponent with a balanced one. What I suggested is the fact that all heaps *must* have a subheap of $2^0$ (this is because all heaps are odd); hence, if all heaps have a subheap of $2^0$, and there are an odd number of heaps; this means that the game begins with an odd number of $2^0$ subheaps, meaning the game begins unbalanced.

Comment: and since the game begins unbalanced, whoever starts the game first (if played intelligently, according to the winning strategy) can always win the game.

Comment: @Camelot823 It is not true that "all heaps are odd". There could be any number of heaps with an even number of coins. But, even with that as the starting assumption, for $\{1, 3, 5 \}$, the correct play is to $\{ 1, 3, 2 \}$ , not to $\{ 1, 3, 1 \}$ like you wanted.    $\quad$ Right, per my hint, we show that Player 1 will win by calculating the Nim score and showing that it is not 0.

Comment: *Show that player 1 can always win a Nim game in which the number of heaps with an odd number of coins is odd.* These are the conditions. The number of heaps are odd. And I didn't advise to play to $\{1,3,1\}$, again, you are misinterpreting. If we start from $\{1,3,5\}$, then all I am saying is that each of the numbers $1,3,5$ have the subheap $2^0$ in them (because they are all odd). We see that $1 = 2^0$, $3 = 2^1 + 2^0$ and $5= 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0$. As we see, they will always have $2^0$ as a subheap. Meaning we have an odd number of subheaps. Meaning the game is unbalanced.

Comment: @Camelot823 Ah, I see what you mean now. You had an excessively long argument about "even + even = even", and weren't talking about how to win.  $\quad$ Note that the critique of "all heaps are odd" is still valid, so I've updated my solution to reflect that.

Comment: How is that false? That's the assumption. The point of the problem is to prove that player one always wins *if* there is an odd number of heaps with an odd number of coins in each. It's not claiming that it is always the case, the problem specifically asks to prove that if that really *is* the case, then player one will win. It can't be false, that's the assumption. Why would we assume a point only to deem it false?

Comment: @Camelot823 The assumption in the question is "number of heaps with an odd number of coins is odd". It does not state any conditions on the number of heaps with an even number of coins. You are assuming that this number is 0. EG The case of $\{ 1, 2, 4, 6 \}$ satisfies "number of heaps with an odd number of coins is odd" but not "all heaps are odd".  $\quad$ In a sense, you are interpreting "If we're given information about Case 1, but not Case 2, then that Case 2 does not exist.". Whereas, in math, the conclusion is "then we have no information about Case 2".

Comment: Any number is either even or odd. The assumption given is: "number of heaps with an odd number of coins is odd". That is: "we have an odd number of heaps, and we have an odd number of coins in each heap". That literally means that we have no even number of heaps, and no even number of coins in any of the heaps. If there were at least one heap with an even number of coins, then it would contradict the assumption that all heaps have an odd number of coins. Case 2 logically can't exist if we assume Case 1.

Comment: @Camelot823 At this point, we have iterated our opinion multiple times, and I don't see value in extending it further. Let's agree to disagree with how to interpret "When no information is provided about heaps with an even number of coins", where you go with "That literally means that we have no even number of heaps, and no even number of coins in any of the heaps. ", and I go with "That literally means we have no information about heaps with an even number of coins".

Comment: How do you agree to disagree on mathematics? The subject is based on pure reason. That does *precisely* mean that we have no information about heaps with an even number of coins; but the funny thing is: the problem doesn't *ask* us to consider the case were the heaps have an even number of coins. It only asks us about Case 1. It only says, show that if Case 1, then player 1 can always win. It doesn't say: "what if Case 2?"

Comment: We are disagreeing on language semantics, not on mathematical reasoning. Consider the statement "Mary's female children are all aged 5". Then you conclude that "Mary has no male children", or maybe even "No one else has any children". Whereas I'm saying "Mary could have some male children, but we don't know any information about them. Everyone else could have children too, but we don't know any information about them."

Comment: I am not at all saying that "Marry has no male children". And the question here is different. It is more like "Consider that Marry has only female children, then prove that...". And you are saying that Marry could have male or female children. But listen to what the problem says, it says "*consider* that Marry has only female children". In our problem, it says *consider* all heaps are odd and have an odd number of coins. We have to prove that player 1 always wins under that consideration.

Comment: @Camelot823 That's where we disagree, and why I'm saying it's language semantics. To me, this is saying "Consider that Mary's female children are aged 5, then prove that ... ". Similarly, the problem says "Consider that there's an odd number of odd heaps, then prove that ..."     There isn't much point in continuing this conversation further, so I'm going to stop replying.